# Resultset para retornar dados do BD - Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, jdbc

Bom, vamos...Estou com uma dúvida, eu tenho um Bd com 3 tabelas e usei inner join para uni-las, e função interna do PostgreSQL para criar uma tabela dinamica, cujo resultado é esse: [image: Resultado da query]

Eu preciso imprimir o resultado linha a linha por exemplo: Loja01; 50; 100; 50; 100; 300.Porem nao sei como acessar A linha e coluna da tabela.Estava pesquisando e vi sobre o metodo getMetaData, mas nao sei como ele se aplicaria nesse caso e nao sei usá-lo de maneira eficiente.
Link do banco para um entendimento melhor: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5c3eb/3.
Obrigado desde já!!!

Comment: Por favor, não fique duplicando a mesma pergunta, ainda mais quando a principal já tem respostas. Comente com os autores caso as respostas não tenham resolvido o problema da sua duvida ao invés de recriar a pergunta.

Comment: Apenas reformulei a pergunta.O que seria "comentar com os autores", é que sou novo por aqui.Os autores sao as pessoas que responderam?

Comment: Exatamente, lembra que te perguntei se a edição era uma duvida diferente e você disse que era a mesma? Então não ha necessidade de recriar a mesma pergunta. Comente abaixo das respostas para que os autores delas saibam que você ainda tem dificuldades com a soluções deles. E paciencia, claro, é domingo e se eles forem brasileiros, estamos em feriado prolongado, pode ser que demorem um pouco a responder mesmo.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela dica.